# How do I retrieve data from SQL server table which has two columns say PatientID and TestNo, Differnt TestNo can have same patient ID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005-express

I have a database (SQL server 2005 Express) table wth columns PatientID (more than 1 records can have same patient ID) and TestNo. I want to retrieve the maximum of testNo column among all the records with same PatientID.What should be the SQL statement to do so?I am using RecordSet pointer to access the records in a vc++ application.

Comment: I mean to say retrieve maximum of testno under the same patientID in the table. What will be the SQL statement to achive this,

Answer (score 0):

Use this SQL:

```
SELECT MAX(TestNo), PatientID
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY PatientID
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do your work:

```
Select max(TestNo) as TestNo, PatientId from TableName group by PatientId
```

This will return you the max of the test no for each of the patient. You can add where condition if you need to take for a particular patient.

Comment: If I want to pass a specific patientID,say BPL000019 what changes should I make

Comment: I would like to retrieve only one record from the table which has the maximum testNo for a given PatientID . I am using ADO recordSet pointer to fetch the record so I need the correct SQL statement so that I can pass it to PrecordSet->Execute function. Kindly help

Comment: What do you mean by maximum testNo? Is it maximum count of test [max(count(tesNo))] or the maximum of the value in testNo [max(testNo)]?

Comment: I am awaiting your reply for my question.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay Mr.KangKan....Among all the records which has same PatientID ,I would like to retrieve the maximum value entered in the TestNo column